# Need Help in Replacing Screen of 3d rotating phone ( AE CC 2018)

Tags: after-effects, animation, greenscreen

First post here! Apologies for any mistakes!

I have a footage of a rotating iPhone with its screen set to green (so I can play around in AE with what to show on the phone screen).

I have tried to manually place my own footage on the screen ( since it's only 30 frames) but of course, that doesn't look good as there are a lot of shaking and inconsistencies.

I tried Mocha in AE but that too doesn't work that well considering this phone rotates in 3d and it's not linear 2D movement.

Tried 3d Camera Tracker in AE but it fails the analysis never succeeds and fails (and IDK why :| )

Attaching required screenshots here. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since it's only 30 frames long, I'd probably do away with tracking and just keyframe it manually using the 'corner pin' effect. Or do a partial track with Mocha AE and supplement the parts that start to drift with corner pinned footage.

Comment: Or use the standard pixel tracking to set up the corner pin.

Comment: hmm, that's what ill end up doing probably! but a one-click solution would have been cool though! ;p